# How to index row number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I have master table and transaction table.

```
1 shipmentheader
2 shimentdetails
```

I have joined (inner join) both table, and data is like

shipmentheader

```
headerid header
---------------
1        h1
2        h2
```

shimentdetails

```
detailid headerid details      createddate
------------------------------------------
1          1          d1
2          1          d2
3          2          d2
```

Now when I joined this two I want to generate row number based on `Headerid` (`shipmentmaster`).

After joining the data would be and sorting should be on details tables `createddate`. I am not  getting below row number, I want to keep number increased based on `HeaderID` order by shipment detail table created date,
if three header id is there then then it will keep row number 1,2,3 and keep same 1,1,2,2 same if joined on details table.

```
RowNumber headerid header details     createddate
-------------------------------------------------
1             1       h1   d1          date
1             2       h1   d3          date
2             2       h2   d2           date
```

Below are queries I tried, but they're not working, also tried `rank()`

```
select 
    row_number() over (partition by sh.ShipmentHeaderID order by sd.createddate) as 'RowNumber',
    sh.headerid, sh.header, sd.details, sd.createddate 
from 
    ShipmentHeader as sh 
inner join 
    ShipmentDetails as sd on sh.ShipmentHeaderID = sd.ShipmentHeaderID


select 
    dense_rank() over (partition by sh.ShipmentHeaderID order by sd.createddate) as 'RowNumber',
    sh.headerid, sh.header, sd.details, sd.createddate 
from 
    ShipmentHeader as sh 
inner join 
    ShipmentDetails as sd on sh.ShipmentHeaderID = sd.ShipmentHeaderID
```

For that I have joined below query with row_number, dense_rank, rank, partition by. But I could not able to get my desire result.

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
 RowNumber headerid header details     createddate
 ------------------------------------------------------
    1             1       h1   d1          date
    1             2       h1   d3          date
    2             2       h2   d2           date
```

Can you please assist me with this?

Comment: should be `dense_rank() over (order by sh.ShipmentHeaderID)`

Comment: @Squirrel, I can but having issue is that we need to display data according to order latest by shipment details createdate(transaction details) table... can you please help by considering this.

Comment: Based on your sample data and expected result, it does not seems that the `RowNumber` is related to the `date`. Perhaps you can post more sample data and the expected result to illustrate this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the data in a particular order, you need an `order by` in the query.  I think this may do what you want:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by sh.ShipmentHeaderID) as RowNumber,
       sh.headerid, sh.header, sd.details, sd.createddate 
from ShipmentHeader sh inner join 
     ShipmentDetails sd 
     on sh.ShipmentHeaderID = sd.ShipmentHeaderID
order by max(sd.createddate) over (partition by sd.headerid) desc,
         sd.headerid;
```

I suspect the header ids are in creation order.  But if they are not, you need a subquery:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by sh.min_createddate, sh.ShipmentHeaderID) as RowNumber,
       sh.headerid, sh.header, sd.details, sd.createddate 
from ShipmentHeader sh inner join 
     (select sd.*,
             min(sd.createddate) over (partition by sd.headerid) as min_createddate
      from ShipmentDetails sd 
     ) sd
     on sh.ShipmentHeaderID = sd.ShipmentHeaderID
order by sd.min_createddate desc, sd.headerid;
```

I'm not sure if you want the ordering increasing or decreasing or if you want the minimum or maximum creation date, so this might need to be tweaked.

Comment: here we have createddate require to consider on details table.so need to list order by DetailsTable date desc. Also keep 10 records per page,and that should row number by Header from ShipmentHeader.... so means, list 10 records par page of Header where having latest modify date desc from  ShpimentDetails table, and need to apply filter,sorting and search on details tables of Details column... I am having trouble in it.